# Adding 2X4 ceiling under lath and plaster

Tags: framing

If my old lath and plaster living room ceiling is solid and I am frame (2X4) and sheetrocking the ceiling 10 inches below the old one  , Can I leave the old ceiling up there or do I have to remove it?

Comment: Given the amount of times I've had to cut through *more than two ceilings*, I think you're good to go. That being said, please for the love of god finish the demo, but making my life easier isn't your prerogative.

Comment: Think long and hard about an acoustic tile drop ceiling. There are many options that don't scream office or school if you get above the absolute cheapest versions.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen this done many time but not 10". The problem with that is any light fixtures would have to be installed in the new ceiling and the wiring from the old fixtures will not reach the new locations so you'd need a junction box in the attic, if you have one, to splice new wire. You could have old knob and tube wiring which could really complicate the problem.

Comment: True the distance may require an additional box in some cases but depending on the type of fixture a cover can be installed and the cable clamp on the cover and the Romex to the new fixture.

Comment: If you could access the original Jbox by removing the light in the new ceiling that might be permissible. 10" might be stretching the limit of practicality however, if you needed to work on that original jbox from below.

Answer (score 3):

You can but installing hat channel on the existing ceiling will be much cheaper and maintain a higher ceiling.  I am guessing you have 9’ ceilings.

Comment: Hat channels will telegraph any dips, or irregularities, which is probably one of the reasons why the OP wants to drop the new ceiling below the old ceiling. Also, adjusting ceiling light fixture trim rings will be difficult too.

Comment: you can do suspended hat channel

Comment: @lee sam , proper shimming will provide a flat ceiling if needed, if there are dips. Actually not much difference from normal deviation in wood products any deviation is easy to see. Add a shim in the gap and it ends up better than the original ceiling.

Comment: @EdBeal So for old sagging ceilings you’re going to shim and then add additional weight. I’d do something independent of the problem and NOT add weight to it. Btw, if you’re recommending screwing through the plaster you should also recommend finding out if it has asbestos.

Comment: The op said the ceiling was in good shap , do you always challenge every thing? Provide a better answer , please ! That’s what the site is for. Not bickering! I said nothing about screwing to the plaster.